# OIDC Provider Flask. Password Credentials Grant

Tags: authlib, flask-oauthlib

Does anybody know wether authlib python library support the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow** for Flask OIDC Provider?

In the documentation only appear Code, Implicit and Hybrid Flow.

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/openid-connect.html

If so, please could you tell me how do you implement the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Password Credentials Grant in OpenID Connect. Password Credentials Grant is a normal OAuth 2.0 grant type, please check https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/grants.html

Here is the documentation of OpenID Connect, you can find it has only code, implicit and hybrid grants: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

Comment: Then, which is the best way to include user's information when using the password credentials grant?